# If and only if <-> indicator_constraints cplex python

Tags: cplex

I use **model.indicator_constraints.add(**ic_dict)** in python complex api to create indicator like this:

i1: `z = 1 -> x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 == 3`

It is implication, but I need if constraint:

i1: `z = 1 <-> x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 == 3`

How to formulate this in python api?

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 constraints for the 2 implies: p implies q and not p implies not q. And to get the negation of q I would use

```
ic_dict["complemented"] = 1
```